# access object variable within array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that holds 'particle' objects, with each particle taking parameters; x position, y position, angle of projection, and velocity.

I am trying to access the x and y positions for each particle within the array to perform further calculations, but I am having trouble with the syntax. Here is a brief summary of the code:

```js
var Particle( x, y , angle, velocity) {            
// here the implementation of the dynamics of the particles are coded 
}
     
// here 100 random particle objects 
// are pushed to the array
   var particleArray = [];
    
for(var i =0; i < 100; i++){

particleArray.push(new Particle( 
               (Math.random()* ( innerWidth  - radius*2) + radius), 
               (Math.random()* ( innerHeight - radius*2) + radius), 
               Math.PI*Math.random(), 5 ))      
}
```

now I want to try and access one of the components 
, for example: the x position of the 47th particle in the array, but I am having trouble like I said above with the syntax or if I have even approached this problem correctly.

Comment: Where does the code at Question get an array element?

Comment: `var Particle( x, y , angle, velocity) {` is invalid syntax, try `var Particle = function( x, y , angle, velocity) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the n-th object in the array via the square bracket notation (note that arrays are 0-indexed): `[n-1]`.

Then you can access a certain property via the dot notation: `object.property`.

```
var x = particleArray[46].x
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the x position 47th particle with `particleArray[46].x`. (Since arrays are "zero-indexed", the first particle is `particleArray[0]`, the second is `particleArray[1]`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example.

> Note that array in javascript are **zero based index** (first position is
>   zero not one) **hence 47th is index 46**

```js
var particles = [];
var innerWidth = 10;
var innerHeight = 5;
var radius = 2;

function Particle(x, y, angle, velocity){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.angle = angle;
  this.velocity = velocity;
}

function generateParticles(numberOfParticles){
  var tempParticles = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfParticles; i++){
    tempParticles.push(
      new Particle( 
          ( Math.random() * (innerWidth - radius * 2) + radius) ,
          ( Math.random() * ( innerHeight - radius * 2) + radius) ,
          Math.PI*Math.random(),
          5 
        )
      );
  }
  return tempParticles;
}

particles = generateParticles(100);
console.log(particles[46])
```

Comment: Thats similar to what I have, but i appreciate the help!